# How to check condition based on user role in jhipster typescript file angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I know how to use hasAnyAuthority directive in jhipster for HTML part. But i am searching how can i do this in typescript part like if user has role farmer navigate to farmer profile, for admin navigate to dashboard.

Comment: Welcome and would you supply us with some code?

Comment: i need like 
if (hasAuthority ="Farmer"){
    this.router.navigate(['farmer']);
} else if (hasAuthority ="Admin"){
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
}

i need that condition value to use for HasAuthority in Jhipster

Comment: You may search for some roles-permissions lib for angular, or create custom user class with role/permissions validation. You will need to load permissions from server and provide User instance into angular DI. 
Then you will be able to inject User whereever you want and check it's permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hasAnyAuthority()` or related functions of `Principal` (see `principal.service.ts`) in a click handler for instance.

Also set `authorities` property on your route's data according to your needs.

```js
export const adminState: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        },
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
        children: ADMIN_ROUTES
    }
];
```

See JHipster doc about authorizations in Angular: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular

Answer (score 1):

Through HTML :

```
*jhiHasAnyAuthority="{authorities: 'ROLE_ADMIN', enable:true/false}"
```

Through TS :

```
this.principal.identity().then(account => {
        if(account.authorities.includes('ROLE_ADMIN')){}
    });
```